# How to bulkify the soql query in this trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, validation

I have been correctly informed by people who know what they are talking about that I should bulkify this code. The code does what it should but needs to be more efficient. Can anyone give concrete code examples what needs to done?

```
trigger trgr_Check_Duplicate_Roles on Key_Staff_People__c (before insert,before update) {


    for (Key_Staff_People__c rsp: Trigger.new) 
        {


            List <Key_Staff_People__c> rcrd = [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c 
                                                WHERE Contact__c = :rsp.Contact__c AND Role__c = :rsp.Role__c];


            if (rcrd.size() > 0)
            {
                if (rsp.Role__c <> Null && rsp.Role__c <> 'Other' )
                {
                    if((Trigger.isUpdate && rcrd[0].Role__c <> Trigger.oldMap.get(rsp.Id).Role__c) || Trigger.isInsert)  trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+rsp.Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: First of all never write SOQL Query in For Loop

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to this question, or in general?  Given you're trying to prevent duplicates, you could just create a field, make it unique, and populate it with a composite key via a workflow rule

Comment: @AdrianLarson nice!

Comment: Obviously, the accepted answer is just flat out wrong there, but there is a detailed demonstration of proper setup if you scroll down far enough. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query for your `rcrd` variables is performed within a `for` loop, which means that query will be executed once per item in your trigger.

i.e.  If you're doing a data load, it will execute for every row in your import file.

The goal is to move the query to before the `for` loop.

In your example however, you're better off creating a new field, making it unique, and using workflow/process builder to add the Contact & Role into it as a composite key.

Expanding on this, if you use a trigger/code approach, you need to check all records within the trigger itself (i.e. duplicate records being inserted, or updates that would result in duplicates) as well as all items already in the database.

If there are duplicates within the trigger, you then need to decide which ones take precedence.  Should all fail? Or should one pass?

A composite key is a much cleaner and easier solution.

Comment: You (Nick) Ratan and Monalisa all deserve kudos for answering this question. It's a pity I can only give credit to one of you. Nick was first so fair is fair. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

[**@Nick Cook**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/359/nick-cook) Already provided you the best solution for this type of problem.

If you still want to go with code then this is one example you can try

```
trigger trgr_Check_Duplicate_Roles on Key_Staff_People__c (before insert,before update) {

    set<Id> setContactIds = new set<Id>();
    set<String> setRoles = new set<String>();

    //first get the contact ids and role in different sets 
    for (Key_Staff_People__c rsp: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if(rsp.Contact__c != null)
            setContactIds.add(rsp.Contact__c);
        if(String.isNotEmpty(rsp.Role__c))
            setRoles.add(rsp.Role__c);
    }
    //based on set values query Key_Staff_People__c
    List <Key_Staff_People__c> rcrd = [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c 
                                                WHERE Contact__c IN: setContactIds AND Role__c IN:setRoles];

    map<String, List<Key_Staff_People__c>>   mapUniqueToLstKeyStaff = new map<String, List<Key_Staff_People__c>> (); 
    //create a map with unique field values ie. Contact__c and Role__c
    for(Key_Staff_People__c rsp: rcrd)
    {
        if(!mapUniqueToLstKeyStaff.containKey(rsp.Contact__c+rsp.Role__c))
            mapUniqueToLstKeyStaff.put(rsp.Contact__c+rsp.Role__c, new List<Key_Staff_People__c>{});
        mapUniqueToLstKeyStaff.get(rsp.Contact__c+rsp.Role__c).add(rsp);
    }
    //now check in map if unique field is exist or not 
    for (Key_Staff_People__c rsp: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if(mapUniqueToLstKeyStaff.containKey(rsp.Contact__c+rsp.Role__c) && mapUniqueToLstKeyStaff.get(rsp.Contact__c+rsp.Role__c).size() > 0)
        {
            if (rsp.Role__c <> Null && rsp.Role__c <> 'Other' )
            {
                if((Trigger.isUpdate && rcrd[0].Role__c <> Trigger.oldMap.get(rsp.Id).Role__c) || Trigger.isInsert)  trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+rsp.Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one.  My brain started to implode when I tried putting the code together.  Is it the sign of a good or bad dev that they go for the simple option of a unique field instead? :)

Comment: @NickCook yeah total agree with you. Since we have easy way. We should go with that

Comment: I had more time to look at the answers. It tried Nick's solution works great but the user is not supposed to see the composite field it would be hidden from the layout and the standard error message is very cryptic. Ratan's code is great. The user knows exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

SOQL queries should not be written in for loop. This will hit governor limits when records are inserted in bulk. You can find the best practices in following link while writing code in apex.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest few improvement in code with lesser number of lines

1. Your code logic suggests you just want to check whether there exist other KeyStaffPeople record in DB with same Role__c and contact__c value in updated/inserted KeyStaffPeople record.
   Simply add Limit 1 in the SOQL query.

`List <Key_Staff_People__c> rcrd = [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c WHERE Contact__c = :rsp.Contact__c AND Role__c = :rsp.Role__c LIMIT 1];`

It is correct that we should avoid using SOQL inside For loop but here using LIMIT 1 in SOQL will ensure that we are not hitting governer limit.

2. `rcrd[0].Role__c <> Trigger.oldMap.get(rsp.Id).Role__c`

I guess here you want to check whether the old value of updated Key_Staff_People__c is same as new update value or not i.e record is actualy updated or not.Instead of using complicated logic you can write it like this

```
for(Id idKeyStaff: Trigger.newMap.keySet())
{
    if(Trigger.oldMap.get(idKeyStaff) !=Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff))
    {
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

Overall Code

```
for(Id idKeyStaff: Trigger.newMap.keySet())
{
    if((Trigger.isInsert || (Trigger.isUpdate &&Trigger.oldMap.get(idKeyStaff) !=Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff))) && Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff).Role__c != Null && Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff).Role__c != 'Other')
    {
        List<Key_Staff_People__c> lstKeyStaff = [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c 
                                            WHERE Contact__c = :Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff).Contact__c AND Role__c = :Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff).Role__c LIMIT 1 ];
        if(!lstKeyStaff.isEmpty())
            Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff).addError('A contact with the role "'+Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff).Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');  
    }
}
```

I believe you dont want to use addError() always for 1st updated/inserted record. Hence updated `Trigger.new[0].addError` to `Trigger.newMap.get(idKeyStaff).addError`

Comment: Great answer. Short and sweet code that even I can understand. One question is how do you know what you can and can not do with Trigger.newMap and oldmap? I see it all the time in peoples code but don't quite understand it.

Comment: I tried your code. I got a null error on this line ---> for(Id idKeyStaff: Trigger.newMap.keySet())